# What's the idiomatic way to have multiple SwiftUI views able to update each other?

Tags: mvvm, swiftui

I'm an iOS and UI first-timer writing a simple app for my daughter to help her make lemonade. Three sliders control ingredients (water, sugar, lemons), and two control taste parameters (sweet and sour). The idea is that for a given sweetness and sourness, adjusting any of the ingredients sliders will update the others to meet the specified sweetness and sourness. You can see the effect below:

[image: App showing all sliders being controlled by other sliders]

As you can see, I've got it working but it's not a great solution; everything is happening in the view in a very imperative fashion, with the slider value change driving the call to `updateIngredients()`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // Initial state recipe is 200g sugar, 1400ml water, 7 lemons
    @State var numLemons: Double = 7
    @State var sugarWeight: Double = 200
    @State var waterWeight: Double = 1400
    
    @State var lemonWaterRatio: Double = 7/1400
    @State var sugarWaterRatio: Double = 200/1400

...

    // Example slider
    Text("Lemons: \(numLemons, specifier: "%.0f")")
    Slider(value: Binding(get: {
        self.numLemons
    }, set: { (newVal) in
        self.numLemons = newVal
        self.updateIngredients("lemons")
    }), in: 0...40, step: 1)
```

I would like to have a view model handle determining the values to show and a model handle the recalculation of ingredients every time any slider value changed, but I cannot figure out how to recalculate all the ingredients without falling into an infinite loop.

I have made the view model `Observable` and published its properties, and bound those to the slider values. This is fine. For the sake of simplicity I'll skip the model and put the ingredients recalculation in the view model:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var display: DisplayCalculator

...

    VStack {
        
        Text("Lemons: \(display.numLemons, specifier: "%.0f")")
        Slider(value: $display.numLemons, in: display.lemons["minValue"]!...display.lemons["maxValue"]!, step: display.lemons["step"]!)

...

}

// View Model
class DisplayCalculator: ObservableObject {
    // Initial state recipe is 200g sugar, 1400ml water, 7 lemons
    @Published var numLemons: Double = 7
    @Published var sugarWeight: Double = 200
    @Published var waterWeight: Double = 1400
    @Published var lemonWaterRatio: Double = 7/1400
    @Published var sugarWaterRatio: Double = 200/1400
    
    let lemons: Dictionary<String, Double> = [  "minValue": 0, "maxValue": 40, "step": 1]

...
    // How can I call this?
    func updateIngredients(_ ingredient: String) {
        switch(ingredient) {
        case "lemons":
            // Set self.sugarWeight and self.waterWeight based on self.lemonWaterRatio and self.sugarWaterRatio
            ...
        }
    }

...

}
```

The problem I run into is that I need to recalculate the whole set of values every time one of them changes. The only way I know to trigger the recalculation is to drive it from `willSet` on the published properties. But all the properties need `willSet` and so when the recalculation updates all the other values, those property observers trigger infinitely.

Is it possible to have any of the sliders able to update all of the others, without driving the calculation from the slider itself?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible approach.

1. First use a `.gesture(TapGesture().onEnded())` on the Slider. This one calls the function to then update your values.
2. Make sure to differentiate in the function call to update your values. Otherwise you will be trapped in, as you already pointed out, infinity loop.
   I did so using a switch statement.

Here is an example of the functioning code:

Note: only the Lemon slider does the Math atm. Add the calculations for the others. I also made the ingredients and the ratios Enums. This helped me to have a cleaner code and made it easier to distinguish between cases.

Tested and working on iOS 13.5

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var display: DisplayCalculator = DisplayCalculator()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Text("Lemons: \(display.numLemons, specifier: "%.0f")")
            Slider(value: $display.numLemons, in: display.lemons["minValue"]!...display.lemons["maxValue"]!, step: display.lemons["step"]!).gesture(TapGesture().onEnded({_ in
                self.display.updateValues(ingredient: Ingredients.numLemons)
            }))
            
            Text("Sugar: \(display.sugarWeight, specifier: "%.0f")")
            Slider(value: $display.sugarWeight, in: 0...2000, step: 10).gesture(TapGesture().onEnded({_ in
                self.display.updateValues(ingredient: Ingredients.sugarWeight)
            }))
            
            Text("Water: \(display.waterWeight, specifier: "%.0f")")
            Slider(value: $display.waterWeight, in: 0...5000, step: 50).gesture(TapGesture().onEnded({_ in
                self.display.updateValues(ingredient: Ingredients.waterWeight)
            }))
            
        }.padding()
    }
}

class DisplayCalculator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var numLemons: Double = Ingredients.numLemons.rawValue
    
    @Published var sugarWeight: Double = Ingredients.sugarWeight.rawValue
    
    @Published var waterWeight: Double = Ingredients.waterWeight.rawValue
    
    let lemons: Dictionary<String, Double> = [  "minValue": 0, "maxValue": 40, "step": 1]

    func updateValues(ingredient: Ingredients) {
        
        switch ingredient {
            case .numLemons  :
                self.waterWeight = self.numLemons/IngredientsMultiplier.lemonWaterRatio.rawValue
                self.sugarWeight = self.waterWeight*IngredientsMultiplier.sugarWaterRatio.rawValue
            case .sugarWeight:
                //do the math
                print("do the math")
            case .waterWeight:
                //do the math
                print("do the math")
        }
    }
    
}

enum Ingredients: Double {
    
    // Initial state recipe is 200g sugar, 1400ml water, 7 lemons
    case numLemons = 7
    case sugarWeight = 200
    case waterWeight = 1400
}

enum IngredientsMultiplier: Double {
    case lemonWaterRatio = 0.005 //7/1400
    case sugarWaterRatio = 0.1428 //200/1400
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: That certainly helps the goal of having a better structured app that helps my daughter make lemonade. I was really hoping to get the realtime updates on the other sliders though to give her really strong visual feedback that shows how the ratios affect the ingredients. Nonetheless, I appreciate the pointer to `.gesture()`

Comment: I was not able to do so. You can modify it to update the values immediately but that causes the gesture recogniser to terminate the recognition. This then makes it impossible to "keep" sliding as you have to repress the slider again. It then is more like a "step" motion slide.

Answer (score 0):

> But all the properties need willSet and so when the recalculation updates all the other values, those property observers trigger infinitely.

You may add a condition check to stop triggering.

```
var lemons = 0 { willSet { if newValue != lemons {updateIngredients("lemon")}}}
var sugar = 0 { willSet { if newValue != sugar {updateIngredients("sugar")}}}
```

The idiomatic way is to create a custom Binding like you did except maybe minor changes in getter/setter. This view model is functionally equivalent to those `@State`, both being bound to a slider.